# How to connect the host on one NIC and the VM on a second NIC

Tags: networking, vmware, network-adapter

I have a win7 host with 2 NIC cards(no wireless) and 1 Win7 VM (Vmware) on the same host. I would like to have the host connected on a network using 1 NIC and i would like the VM connected on the second NIC on a different network.  For security reason I dont want the VM to be able to see the other network (host network) or the other way around.  Do you think that's possible ? And how it would need to be setup ?  It's important that they don't see each other for security reason.

Thank you very much.

Comment: it may be relevant what software u r using e.g. vmware or virtualbox 'cos usually people answering, unfortunately, don't have the willingness to post solutions for both.. and also unfortunately, people answering are often only familiar with one of the pieces of software and would typically not answer unless u stated which u want an answer for. So in practise it's worth stating which software u're using,whether it's vmware, virtualbox, or something else. If u don't mind which then maybe say vmware 'cos IIRC i've heard it can do more (assuming I remember correctly and assuming it's still true)

Comment: Whatever your virtualization platform, this is done by editing the virtual network (at least on all VM products I've used), so we need to know what virtualization platform we are talking about in order to provide instructions.

Comment: Hi, i'm using VMware. I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: Is this VMware Workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest answer would be to:

1. connect VmWare's Bridged virtual network (VMnet0) to the correct nic.
2. Edit the VM network adapter to use Bridged networking.

To perform step 1, go to Edit -> Virtual Network Editor.

1. Select the VMnet0 virtual switch.
2. Select "Bridged" below the list.
3. Select your hardware NIC from the "Bridged to:" dropdown list.
4. Uncheck "Connect a host virtual adapter to this network" to isolate the network from the host on the virtual switch.

To perform step 2,

1. select the VM in question.
2. go to VM -> Settings -> Hardware and select your network adapter.
3. set the adapter to bridged mode.

More info and a video describing the general editing of vNics and vSwitches here: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697